# Subclassing NSImageView with the binding ability

Tags: swift, appkit, key-value-observing, cocoa-bindings, nsimageview

I'm trying to animate the image change in NSImageView. It is a purely academic problem, and I'm staying within the restrictions of a macOS binding framework.

Please, consider the model:

```
class Model: NSObject {
    /// Image object for the NSImageView
    @objc dynamic var image: NSImage?
    /// The target action for button `A`.
    /// Changes the image inside model.
    /// The change is not a KVO compliment because such a change is 'inside' the model.
    @objc func a() {
        self.image = NSImage(named: "a")
    }
    /// The target action for the button B
    /// In the window UI
    @objc func b() {
        self.image = NSImage(named: "b")
    }
}
```

[image]

It is the simplest and strait-forward binding example from the bible ([What Are Cocoa Bindings?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html)). The difference I want to achieve is to make the image change process visible to the user.

I will intercept every new image moving to the NSImageView from NSObjectController and transit it with the old one.

```
class AnimatedImageView: NSImageView {

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        // The code execution is never through this point.
        if key == "image" {
            self.transition(value as! NSImage?)
        } else {
            super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    private func transition(_ newImage:NSImage?) {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 1
        transition.type = .fade
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        self.layer?.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        self.image = newImage
    }

}
```

The attempt to override the method `setValue(_:forKey:)` was not successful.
Despite this, I know that the method `bind(...)` is firing well, and the application itself is working well, except for animation.

What I missed?

Please, find attached the project source is [there](https://github.com/kazumov/animated-image-view/tree/main/Image%20transition%20animation).

Comment: What makes you expect `setValue` to be called? Or put another way: what do you think should be calling `setValue`?

Comment: What is the end goal? What do you wanna achieve?

Comment: @Sajjon I am implementing the fade in/out `NSImage` change in an `ImageView.`

Comment: @Sweeper I expect the `setValue` delivers the `NSValue? as Any?` from the model to the `MyImageView.image` by KVO. I did such a trick with an `NSTableColumn` subclass before, and everything was OK, but this time I stuck with the problem, that `MyImageView` do not call overridden `setValue.`

Comment: Which binding do you use?

Comment: If you use the value binding then override the `objectValue` property.

Comment: @Willeke, I love it! Thank you so much! I precisely looked for this property. Please, put this line in the answer, and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value binder calls the Objective-C method `setObjectValue:`. In Swift, override the `objectValue` property.